# 'flatpicker' datepicker model validation not working in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used flatpicker datepicker. In this field asp.net model validation is not working.

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label asp-for="txtDate" class="required">From Date</label>
   <input asp-for="txtDate" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY" />
   <span asp-validation-for="txtDate" class="fv-error"></span>
</div>


$("#txtDate").flatpickr({
    format: "d-m-Y",
    altFormat: "d-M-Y",
    minDate: new Date(),
    altInput: true,
});

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Start Date")]
public string? txtDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Did you add `@section Scripts{}` out of `$("#txtDate").flatpickr({})`?

Comment: I am using already the inside Scripts section like...
`@section Scripts
{
<script>
$("#txtDate").flatpickr({});
</script>
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It is working properly.

```
$("#txtDate").flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d-M-Y"
});
```